# ElasticSearch Cluster on AKS with loadbalancer

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, azure-aks, amazon-elb

I am trying to deploy elasticsearch to AKS with a loadbalancer.

What I am struggling to achieve is to have a load balancer that only directs traffic to my client nodes.

This is what I have:

ElasticSearch dployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.16.2
  nodeSets:
  # 3 dedicated master nodes
  - name: master
    count: 3
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
        - name: sysctl
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
    config:
      node.roles: ["master"]
      #node.remote_cluster_client: false
  # 3 ingest-data nodes
  - name: ingest-data
    count: 3
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
        - name: sysctl
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
    config:
      node.roles: ["data", "ingest"]
  # 3 client nodes
  - name: client
    count: 3
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
        - name: sysctl
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
    config:
      node.roles: []
```

Load Balancer YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-controller
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/cluster-name: "quickstart"
    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-master: "false"
    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-data: "false"
    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-ingest: "false"
    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-ml: "false"
    elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/node-transform: "false"
```

Output of `kubectl get svc ingress-controller` (public ip redacted)

```
NAME                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
ingress-controller   LoadBalancer   10.0.221.180   20.0.0.95   9200:32360/TCP   54m
```

This loadbalancer does not repond with anything on port 9200 so I suspect its not working anyway but I am not sure how to achieve what im trying to do at all.

Thankyou in advance. I appriciate any tips on how to solve this.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [sf].

Comment: Can you paste the output of `kubectl get svc ingress-controller`?

Comment: @gohm'c Output of command added above.